# How do I connect Shopify Private app to Quickwork?

Tags: node.js, shopify

I'm unable to connect my Shopify App with Quickwork Platform. How do I get my Admin API access token and Storefront access token from the Shopify Platform?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 – Go to app development in the left corner and click
on develop new app, give name

Step 2 – Once you click on ‘ Create new app’ you will be
redirected to overview. There you can select configuration option

Step 3 – click on ‘Admin API configuration’  - Configure option and check all the boxes and
hit SAVE. You will get admin api key which you can reveal, copy paste to
journey

Step 4 – Click on Storefront API integration –
configure option and check all boxes and save. Copy and paste the api key to
journey to link the account